# Sql Server with Docker Compose gives error - Internal: stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am creating a simple .Net Web Application with Docker support. I have following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  funeventapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}funeventapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FunEventApi/Dockerfile
    environment:
      - IS_DOCKER_PROCESS=true
  funeventdb:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: FunEventDb/DockerSetup/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1430:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=myStrongPassword!
```

But there seems to be an issue with setting-up a db container(since just api works fine). Whenever I am trying to run docker compose I am getting following error:

`Error  DT1001  failed to solve: Internal: Internal: Internal: stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: INTERNAL_ERROR`

My sql Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest

ARG PROJECT_DIR=/tmp/FunEvent
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR
WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR
COPY DockerSetup/CreateDb.sql ./
COPY DockerSetup/entrypoint.sh ./
COPY DockerSetup/setup.sh ./

CMD ["/bin/bash", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

I tried to restart docker, update it but it doesn't help.

I also checked the image with CMD running following command:
`docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=myStrongPassword!" -p 1430:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest`
And it runs just fine and I get access to server.

Entrypoint.sh script: `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & ./setup.sh`

Setup.sh script:

```
sleep 60s
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -i CreateDb.sql -U sa -P "$SA_PASSWORD"
```

Comment: So what are you doing in `entrypoint.sh`?  Since you're replacing the `CMD` (ref: [Dockerfile](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/linux/mssql-server-linux/Dockerfile)) it's going to be your responsibility to start the `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr` process.

Comment: I added scripts contents to post, they are doing what you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

So after retries and experiments I was able to get rid off this error by moving by sql Dockerfile to other folder, on the same level as docker compose folder. I still don't know why this was the problem but I hope this might will help someone.

[folders arrangement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZHRR.png)